Configure fail2ban to parse multiple log lines, e.g. Postfix mail rejects
I want to to block local authenticated mail users who generate spam, i.e. disable their SMTP access for a while as one of several countermeasures against hijacked accounts and malware.
To accomplish this I have created a fail2ban filter, jail and action which looks like this:
# jail.d/postfix-rejects.conf
[postfix-rejects]
enabled = true
filter = postfix-rejects
logpath = /var/log/mail.log
maxretry = 20
findtime = 600
bantime = 3600
action = postfix-rejects

# action.d/postfix-rejects.conf
[Definition]
actionstart =
actionstop =
actioncheck =
actionban = /usr/local/sbin/toggle_smtp_access.sh <ADDR> ban
actionunban = /usr/local/sbin/toggle_smtp_access.sh <ADDR> unban

# filter.d/postfix-rejects.conf
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf
[Definition]
_daemon = postfix/cleanup
failregex = "sasl_username=<ADDR><SKIPLINES>.*milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from <\S+>: 5.7.1 Spam message rejected"

The problem is that I need both the "sasl_username=" and the "Spam message rejected" log line to ensure that it's the same user, so I need to merge two - not necessarily consecutive - log file lines.
However, this does not work. Testing this regular expression finds nothing in the logs although I know there are some occurrences. (Example below)

Is there any better method of dealing with this? Can I maybe get Postfix to combine authentication and rejection lines?
If not, what would a suitable regexp for fail2ban be to catch these lines?

Example log output which should produce a hit (for fail2ban) and return EMAIL:
Jun 22 23:17:11 root postfix/smtps/smtpd[3244715]: connect from unknown[<IP6>]
Jun 22 23:17:11 root postfix/smtps/smtpd[3244715]: CA4452541xxx: client=unknown[<IP6>], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=<EMAIL>
Jun 22 23:17:11 root postfix/cleanup[3244717]: CA4452541xxx: message-id=<a0b28688-3110-4530-8f4d-9948e448952f@....>
Jun 22 23:17:11 root postfix/cleanup[3244717]: CA4452541xxx: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from unknown[<IP6>]: 5.7.1 Spam message rejected; from=<EMAIL> to=<EMAIL2> proto=ESMTP helo=<[IPV6:<IP6>]>

Matching of lines should only occur when the session IDs (CA44....) and EMAIL strings are identical.

You need to set maxlines in your filter config.
